# Jira REST API - "Field 'customfield_12305' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown"

Tags: jira-rest-api

When trying to create a new issue, I get the following error:

```
response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_12305":"Field 'customfield_12305' cannot be set. 
It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."}}
```

I've found a lot of posts related to this error, with all of them saying the solution is to verify that the screen mapped to the "Create Issue" operation needs to have this custom field on it and available. I've verified that I do indeed have this custom field on that screen (as well as all of the other screens used in the target project, but I'm still getting this error.  Also, I am able to set values for 2 other custom fields (Epic Name, Story Points), and they are already configured for the same screens.

What else might be a contributing factor here, and/or how else can I troubleshoot this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally discovered that although the field was already included in all of the relevant screens, a Field Scheme had to be applied to the target projects.  Once this was done, everything worked fine. /smh

Comment: How do you apply a Field Scheme?

Comment: I believe it depends on the platform, ie server/datacenter vs. cloud, but check these articles https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/what-are-issue-field-configuration-schemes/ and https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/configure-a-field-configuration-scheme/

Answer (score -2):

This normally means you are trying to modify an issue that is already closed or in any state on which modifying its properties is not allowed anymore...

you can reopen the issue → edit your "custom field" → closed again

Comment: Nonsense! The error doesn't have anything to do with the Issue status.